# Response variable (a percentile) is uniform and identically distributed but not independent?

Tags: multiple-regression, modeling, regression-coefficients, independence, uniform-distribution

Imagine the following problem:

$(X,U,Y)$ is drawn from one of $n$ groups where X are the explanatory variables and $U$ is some quantity (a ratio if that’s relevant). The response variable $Y$ is the percentile of $U$ in the group/population k={1,2,...,n} that (X,U,Y) was drawn from. Now if I’m not mistaken Y~Uniform(0,1), regardless of the group k, so it is also identically distributed when we pool all n groups together. However Y (within a group) is not independent because if I know that a particular u in group k is very large then that gives me information about the y’ corresponding to a future u’ drawn from group k.

With this in mind, how would you regress Y on X? I see that beta regression handles uniformly distributed response variables but I think it does assume the first i in iid. If n in the sample population is large enough (large enough to have most of the groups in the “universe”? relative to the population size in each of the n groups? or it doesn’t matter?), i.e. there is good “breadth”, is that approximately independent? The end purpose is to evaluate the impact of feature X_i, also a percentile within group k of some quantity, on Y—after accounting for the other features that is.

Do tell if at any point in this described procedure, something was done that doesn’t make sense!

Comment: The are on group level, so you have n observations from n groups? Can you explain how the percentile where calculated?

Comment: n groups, m observations each. the percentile of an observation in a group is based on only the other observations in that group. of course, when i build a model i am assuming that for all the groups, the response variable is related to the explanatory variables in the same way/very similar ways

Comment: i should add, m_n observations each. but i don’t think it’ll matter much, think we can assume m for sake of generality